# how to add pushpins on map in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, pushpin

Is there any tutorial or sample that shows how to add pushpin on a map in windows phone 8.1 
this code is not working:

```
MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
MapIcon1.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
{
    Latitude = latitude,
    Longitude = -longitude
 });
 MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
 RestoMap.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);
```

Answer (score 2):

MapIcon objects are not guaranteed to be displayed on the map, they can be obscured by other elements.

If you want to put something that will always be visible, use XAML controls:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792121.aspx#showing_xaml_controls_and_shapes_on_the_map

Comment: is this code correct for binding the location:
<TextBlock maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" Text="{Binding Name}" maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5" FontSize="20" Margin="5"/>
Location location = new Location();
location.Latitude = latitude;
location.Longitude = longitude;
locations.Add(location);
}
MapIcons.ItemsSource = this.locations;

Comment: @ahmad I am using similar code, but the maps:MapControl.Location needs to be bound to a Geopoint value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapIcons" >
    <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             ........
             .......
        </DataTemplate>
     </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </Maps:MapItemsControl>

class MapIcon
{
   public String id { get; set; }
   public String name { get; set; }
   public String description { get; set; }
   public String picture { get; set; }
   public Geopoint MapLocation { get; set; }
}

funtion
{
     Double latitude = item.latitude;
     Double longitude = item.longitude;
     Geopoint location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
     {
        Latitude = latitude,
        Longitude = longitude,
     });
     MapIcon icon = new MapIcon() { MapLocation = location, name = name, picture = picture ,description = description};
     icons.Add(icon);
}
MapIcons.ItemsSource = icons;
```